# Increment column value in web2py DAL

Tags: web2py

I want to write a query which will increment the current integer value in the given column by 1. I am trying this but its not working:

```
db(db.mes.id==meid).update(status=status+1)
```

Please let me know how do I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a `Field` object in the expression:

```
db(db.mes.id == meid).update(status=db.mes.status + 1)
```